# Iterate over a list of objects getting ke/value pairs

Tags: python, list

I'd like to iterate over a list of objects (where I don't know their keys) in as simple way as possible, without creating unnecessary temp variables.

So let's say that's my array :

```
y = [{'faz': 'baz'}, {'foo': 'bar'}]
```

Getting k, v from object can be easily done with `iteritems()` but is it possible to iterate over list using lambda at the same time ?

EDIT

---

Pseudocode:

```
for k, v in x where x is an array item
```

Comment: `iterate over list using lambda` - What do you mean by that?

Comment: What do you mean by "using lambda at the same time"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why do you have a list of single-element dictionaries?

Comment: I have a list since my keys can be like 'This is some key' or 'This is a totally useless key'.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question...

Comment: It does. I need to be sure of ordering and I don't know the key names upfront (and the keys itself are sentences).

Comment: He's just telling (i think) you that the data structure might not be appropriate ... if you created that list, you might as well have created one single `dict` upfront.

Comment: That's *closer* to an answer, but perhaps you should edit the question with some more background? What is the task you're trying to accomplish? If you need a mapping but with order, consider `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your keys are unique across the list, you can do:

```
for k, v in {k:v for l in y for k, v in l.iteritems()}.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

or equivalently,

```
y2 = {k:v for l in y for k, v in l.iteritems()}
for k, v in y2.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

but it is not very pretty.

If all your dict have one one key-value pair, you can do this:

```
for k,v in map(lambda x: x.items()[0], y):
    print k, v
```

Another solution is the following which just iterates over the list and then over the dict:

```
def items(lis):
    for l in lis:
        for k, v in l.iteritems():
            yield k, v

for k, v in items(y):
    print k, v
```